# In Lucas-Kanade Optical Flow Method, what can be the maximum Euclidean Distance between tracked point pairs?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, opticalflow, feature-tracking

I am using Lucas-Kanade Optical Flow Method to track the points from one image to the next one. In OpenCV, there is an easy to use [function](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga473e4b886d0bcc6b65831eb88ed93323):

```cpp
void cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK (
    InputArray       prevImg,
    InputArray       nextImg,
    InputArray       prevPts,
    InputOutputArray nextPts,
    OutputArray      status,
    OutputArray      err,
    Size             winSize = Size(21, 21),
    int              maxLevel = 3,
    TermCriteria     criteria = TermCriteria(TermCriteria::COUNT+TermCriteria::EPS, 30, 0.01),
    int              flags = 0,
    double           minEigThreshold = 1e-4 
)
```

After I got the tracked points in `nextPts`, I iterated through all the point pairs and calculated the Euclidean distance:

```cpp
    diff_x = prev_pt.x - curr_pt.x;
    diff_y = prev_pt.y - curr_pt.y;
    euclidean_dist = sqrt(pow(diff_x, 2) + pow(diff_y, 2));
```

During the iterations, I also kept the track of maximum distance and to my surprise it turned out to be as high as around **500 px**!! How's that even possible!? Because the size of the search window at each pyramid level i.e. `winSize` is set to `cv::Size(21, 21)`. So, the maximum distant point pairs will look like this:

[image: Lucas-Kanade Opt Flow - Search Window]

Hence, from my understanding, for `winSize = cv::Size(21, 21)`, the maximum distance cannot go beyond `14.14 px`, right?

(Here is how I got `14.14` number):

```
Pi = cv::Point(10, 10)
Pj = cv::Point(20,  0)
diff_x = 10
diff_y = 10
euclidean_dist = sqrt(10^2 + 10^2) 
               = sqrt(200) 
               = 14.14
```

So, I don't understand why I'm getting the maximum Euclidean distance between tracked point pairs as high as around 500 px.

As per the OpenCV documentation, the parameter description for `winSize` says:

> winSize - size of the search window at **'each'** pyramid level.

Does that mean `winSize` remains constant even when the image is down-scaled in the pyramid? Because of that, some point pairs might be within the search window at upper levels of the pyramid?

Comment: Yes sure, the pyramid is used to extend the search region in an efficient way. Still, with 3 (or 4?) levels and naive binary pyramid, it would lead to a maximum distance of 113.  But I don't know whether the pyramid has a bigger subdivision factor or it is handed-over on the coarsest level.

Comment: brightness constancy assumption underlies the algorithm. practically, numerics ruin that a little. LK doesn't just match a window. it uses a difference/gradient. that can send you far away if the numerics make it happen. It's somewhat like numerical root finding. I'd suggest setting up an 1D toy example, a signal you can manipulate interactively, and implementing the numerics for yourself on that.

Comment: @Micka I don't think I completely understood your statement: _"But I don't know whether the pyramid has a bigger subdivision factor or it is handed-over on the coarsest level."_

But I did try playing with the `maxLevel` parameter and even with its value = `0` (i.e. pyramids are not used -- single level), the max Euclidean Distance was nowhere close to `14.14`. It was still in the range of `500`s!

Comment: @Micka Also, in your statement, _"Still, with 3 (or 4?) levels and naive binary pyramid, it would lead to a maximum distance of 113"_, how did you come up with the number `113`? As I have explained/thought in my question, the max Euclidean distance cannot/should not be more than `14.14` px.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I appreciate your suggestion. However, to implement that, I will have to dig way deeper into the Lucas Kanade algorithm. That's why I thought someone with more experience may have some good idea/insight about what's going on and why I am getting such a high maximum Euclidean distance. TIA!

Comment: 14.14*2*2*2 for 3 binary subdivisions.